# Javascript: function that does one thing if php variable is define

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have an SQL table that is updated through PHP. On an editJob page, you can navigate to it and enter a job number in a text box that then inserts that job number into the SQL and creates an entry. You can then add operations to the job number.
However, what I want to be able to do is navigate to the page with PHP variables entered into the URL which then autofill the text box with the job number from the URL.
I can't figure out how to check whether this PHP variable is present in my javascript.

Here is the relevant javascript below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jobCheckCallback (data) {

    if (data.includes("<td")) {
    alert("Job already exists. Edit this job by clicking Edit on the job's overview page");
    document.getElementById("jobID").value = 0;
    } else {
    var njobID = document.getElementById("jobID").value;
    if (njobID == "") njobID = 0;
        else njobID= <?php echo $jobID; ?>;
        sendAsync("editDatabase.php?sql=UPDATE+customerlist+SET+jobID="+njobID+" WHERE+jobID=" +jobID);
        sendAsync("editDatabase.php?sql=UPDATE+operations+SET+jobID="+njobID+" WHERE+jobID="+jobID);
        sendAsync("editDatabase.php?sql=UPDATE+jobfiles+SET+jobID="+njobID+" WHERE+jobID="+jobID);
        sendAsync("editDatabase.php?sql=UPDATE+pallets+SET+jobID="+njobID+" WHERE+jobID="+jobID);
        sendAsync("editDatabase.php?sql=UPDATE+jobs+SET+jobID="+njobID+" WHERE+jobID="+jobID,function(id){
        return function(){
                setjobID(id);
        }
    }(njobID));
  }
}
</script>
```

The error message I get is "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" but I'm guessing its another issue causing this error.

EDIT: $jobID is the PHP variable that can be entered into the URL, and is then autofilled into the textbox on the page.

Comment: You're missing some closing curly braces `}` but more importantly **Do not execute SQL that was sent by the user!** Tjat is a huge vulnerability! Imagine if someone decided to send `DELETE FROM customerlist`?? That would be bad. You should have a page you send jobIDs to that performs all of the actions (call it updateJobId.php or something)

Comment: Those missing } curly braces didn't come through when I pasted them here, but they're there now.

Comment: And the people who'll be using this system aren't the computer-savvy people so I'm willing to risk the vulnerabilities, but I do appreciate your concern.

Comment: alright... anyway, the answer is to use `<?php echo json_encode($jobID); ?>` I'm betting the jobID is blank so it's causing an error in the JS

Comment: Projects like this tend to grow into bigger things.  Do yourself a favor and heed @Eksepshon's advice -- pass the data back to `PHP` and let PHP assemble the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the resulting page source?  I suspect you need to wrap the php output statement with quotes so:

```
else njobID= '<?php echo $jobID; ?>';
```

So if job ID is empty it won't result in invalid js.

Comment: Thank you, I actually didn't think of that.